# What is preferred using Pod or not in React Native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

> ### I get confuse either to use or not to use pod.
>
> There are usually procedure to add modules for both procedures i.e using pod and using npm however using pod steps seems quick. But is there any problems using it with React Native or not.
>
> ### Need help from experts , which is the best practise and why ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for this issue. I used this extends to support Cocopod into the react-native project.

command of install:

```
npm i react-native-pod
```

the commands of usage:

```
yarn add react-native-pod
react-native link
```

and finally add pods you would like distributed with your package from the command line::

```
react-native addpod [pod]
```

for more information see: [react-native-pod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pod)